# Tag Synonym Suggestions

Tags: discussion

In the chat meeting we held tonight we decided it would be better to discuss tag synonyms here, where it's possibly easier to refer to later.

(For those needing a primer on tag synonyms, you can read up on them at the [SO blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/tag-folksonomy-and-tag-synonyms/). For some examples of tag synonyms, you can check SO's [master list of synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?filter=all&tab=master). If you can't be bothered to do either: tl;dr - tag synonyms map tags onto other tags - for example `rails` onto `ruby-on-rails`)

If we could keep it to a single synonym or a closely related set of synonyms per answer it would enable us better coordinate the discussion in the comments.

Currently the rep requirements for creating and voting on tag synonyms are 2500 rep, and at least 10 answer reputation in the tags involved. This is the same as SO and don't really fit in with the reputation levels of our site, which means that we'll have to organise this across those with the prerequisite levels of reputation.

Comment: Can you explain here why it's important to focus on this and why we can't just rely on synonyms to correct for us?

Answer (score 3):

`[plugins]` -> `[plugin]`

Again, discussed in chat, the singular form appears to be more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

`[themes]` -> `[theme]`

Discussed in chat, we generally decided that the singular form was more appropriate.